# Ajaxcombox listitems shows only text width in chrome

Tags: asp.net

Ajax combobox itemlists taking only text width in Chrome (Version 25.0.1364.152 m) .
Width is set to 120px of UL, but it is taking only 36px.

in other browser it is working fine.

apart from that in WinXP and Chrome same combobox  Displays in Wrong Place, it goes approx 350px below to parent.

```
.ftbox7 input{ width:80px; height:18px; float:left; border:1px solid #ebdaa5;} 
<div class=ftbox7>
<ajax:ComboBox ID="cmbLocation" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
               AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CaseSensitive="False"        
               CssClass="ajaxSmallComboBox" ItemInsertLocation="Append" MaxLength="10"          
               AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="LocationCode"      
               DataValueField="LocationId">
</ajax:ComboBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code, please

Comment: <div class="ftbox7">
    <ajax:ComboBox ID="cmbLocation" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
        CaseSensitive="False" CssClass="ajaxSmallComboBox" ItemInsertLocation="Append" MaxLength="10"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="LocationCode" DataValueField="LocationId">
    </ajax:ComboBox>
</div>

Comment: .ftbox7 input{ width:80px; height:18px; float:left; border:1px solid #ebdaa5;}

Comment: You should have posted it in your question, there is an edit button below your post. I fixed it for you, but try to make your questions as clear as possible in order to get help.

Comment: i am not able to find your answer in your comment.